# Access session variable in IFRAME created withn a main page

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I have created Code in PHP.as follows.

I have index.php as main page and its having following structure.

```
<table>

    <tr><td><?PHP $_session['id']=$id; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><iframe ....></iframe></td></tr>

</table>
```

now when I am trying to access session variable from the page which is being loaded in iframe,
the variable is not bbeing accessed or it is not set for the page loaded in the IFRAME.

As the page loaded in IFRAME is located in the same server same Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Most browser won't allow cookie from iframe and as session in PHP rely on them, you won't be able to access them.

Multiple shim exist in order to allow cookie from iframe, like P3P header for IE.

Although, Safari third party policy is way harder to bypass, and so you'll probably have to simply change the way you use session. You can set session manually and use ids you travel between client and server (PHP offer a way to do somethinh similar), or on facebook you can rely on the signed_request / getLoginStatus to manage authentification in your app.